# Why does $f$ need to be rational in this argument as opposed to just meromorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a rational function with all of its poles in $\mathbb{D}$, the unit disk. Define the function $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z})$. Show that $f$ has a primitive in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ if and only if $\text{Res}(g\,\,; z=0)=0$. The forward direction is decently trivial by computing the integral $\int_\gamma g(z)\,\text{d}z$ for any closed curve $\gamma$ in the unit disk and noting that $g(z)=-\frac{d}{dz}F(\frac{1}{z})$ if $F$ is the primitive of $f$.

For the backward direction, since $g$ is analytic on the punctured unit disk, it has a Laurent series $g(z)=\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} a_kz^k$, where $a_{-1}=0$. Now using the definition of $g$ and setting $\zeta=\frac{1}{z}$, we see that the Laurent series of $f(\zeta)$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ has no $\zeta^{-1}$ term, hence when we compute the integral $\int_{\gamma} f(\zeta)\,\text{d}\zeta$ term by term (allowable by general power series theory as far as I am aware), where $\gamma$ is any closed curve in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, we get 0. Thus $f$ has an anti-derivative there. It doesn't seem to me that I have used the fact that $f$ is rational. Did I make an error? The problem set up explicitly states that $f$ is rational, so it seems to me it should be used somewhere.

Comment: your argument seems right to me but i am a non-expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More simply,

because $f(w)$ is analytic on $|w|>1$,

you can express $f(w)$ as the sum $g(w)+k(1/w)$,

where $g(z)$ is a function holomorphic on the range $z\in\mathbb{C}$

and $k(z)$ is a function holomorphic on the range $|z|<1$ such that $k(0)=0$.

This is what the theorem on Laurent series tells you.

$\\$

Now, you can find the primitive of $g(w)$ easily. Let's call that primitive $G(w)$.

As for $k(1/w)$,

let $\displaystyle k(z)=b_1 z+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty b_n z^n$ on the open unit disc.

Show that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{b_n}{1-n} z^n$ is the Taylor series of a function $j(z)$ that is also holomorphic on the open unit disc. Show that $j(1/w)$ is the primitive of $k(1/w)-b_1/w$ on the range $|w|>1$.

$\\$

Now, $f(w)$ has a primitive on $|w|>1$ if and only if $f(w)-d/dw\big[G(w)+j(1/w)\big]=b_1/w$ has a primitive on $|w|>1$.

Therefore, the only thing left to check here is whether $b_1=0$.

Comment: But you didn't answer my question though. Does $f$ need to be rational?

Comment: @MSA2016 no. The argument does not depend on that